# Handling event of user control in its holding page's code behind

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am looking for a solution for following situation.

In my application i had a page say page1 and i placed a user control inside the page1. My requirement is i need to get the click event of button used in user control on page1's code behind. How i can achieve the same in windows phone / silverlight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 1. The first and the right way:

(If you are aware of MVVM pattern) would be for you control, say `MyControl`, to expose DependencyProperty of type `ICommand`, named e.g. MyControlButtonClickCommand.

Xaml:

```
<UserControl>
    <Button Command={Binding MyControlButtonClickCommand, Source={RelativeSource Self}} />
</UserControl>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public ICommand MyControlButtonClickCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyControlButtonClickCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyControlButtonClickCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlButtonClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyControlButtonClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

You'd use you UserControl as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

    <namespace:MyControl MyControlButtonClickCommand="{Binding ControlButtonCommand}" />

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Where `ControlButtonCommand` is a property of a ViewModel (your custom object), living in a DataContext of your `Page`.

### 2. There is also a simpler and dirtier way which I discourage you to go:

Just like you expose `MyControlButtonClickCommand` dependency property and instead of exposing it, you can expose an event `MyControlButtonClick` and in the Page's xaml subscribe to it. Internally in your UserControl's code you should subscribe to it's button's `Click` event and fire its own `MyControlButtonClick` event.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need this, could you please add some more code, so  that i could follow your process. Where to add this `<namespace:MyControl ../>` How do I bind the viewModel command to usercontrol's buttonclick? please help new to wpf windows phone ...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it,
simplest would be double click the button on the presentation layout.

Or

in XML add onCLick=
doing this would popup the menu to select new event. click on that and you event for button click should be there on the code behind.

```
<button name="b1" onClick="button1_Click()"/> <!--this is what ur XAML will look like -->
```

to handle the button click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the click event here

}
```

Comment: To handle the button click event, you need to register a click event for that button. The above method with do so, and it will generate a stub like "Button1_clicked()" in this method you will handle the event

Comment: @Harshit You didn't understand his question. He meant to handle the UserControl's button click in the code behind of the Page, not the UserControl itself.

Comment: @nkchandra Ok, i got that for the answer posted above.

Answer (score 0):

For the UserControl you can create an interface which your Page1.xaml.cs will implement.

```
public partial Class SomeControl : UserControl
{
    private OnButtonClick button_click;

    public interface OnButtonClick
    {
        void someMethod();   // generic, you can also use parameters to pass objects!!
    }

    // Used to add interface to dynamic controls
    public void addButtonClickInterface(OnButtonClick button_click)
    {
        this.button_click = button_click;
    }

    // Buttons UserControlled Click
    private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(button_click != null)
        {
            button_click.someMethod();  
        }
    }

}
```

Here is how to implement it and use it.

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage, SomeControl.OnButtonClick
{

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent()

        // for a new Control
        SomeControl cntrl = new SomeControl();
        cntrl.addButtonClickInterface(this);

        // or for a control in your xaml
        someControl.addButtonClickInterface(this);
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
        // Here is where your button will trigger!!
    }

}
```