# Is it possible to create a custom routed event in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: visual-studio, user-controls, windows-phone-8, routed-events

I have a user control and I'm currrently trying to implement a custom routed event in it according to this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx

I get an error saying that "The name 'EventManager' does not exist in the current context".
I've tried to add it by writing `using System.Windows.EventManager` but there is no such namespace.
Question is if it's possible at all to create custom routed events in windows phone 8 applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make any custom routed events in WP8. Instead you can make use of dependency properties along with I command. So you can route your events according to you wish. Try this:
[handling event of user control in its holding page's code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678211/handling-event-of-user-control-in-its-holding-pages-code-behind).